# How to get for loop to append results to a list, then count the occurance of each unique item in the list

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a for loop that starts from the first business in a list, then compares that business' coordinates to a list of crimes that have happened. If the crime it scans is <= .25 mi, i want to add that name to a list and then count how many crimes were within that radius. Here is my code so far:

```
crime_list = []
crime_number = []

for row in autorepair_df.itertuples():
    auto = (row.lat, row.lon)
    name = (row.name)
    for row in parts_and_vehicle_theft.itertuples():
        crime =(row.GEO_LAT, row.GEO_LON)
        crimecount = geodesic(auto,crime).mi
        if crimecount <= .25:
            crime_list.append(name)
    Counter(crime_list)
    print(Counter)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this result repeated:

```
<class 'collections.Counter'>
```

What I'm trying to ultimately do is have a dataframe that lists the auto repair shops and then the next column would have a count of how many crimes are near it. I feel like I'm close to getting my result, but might be missing some lines of code somewhere.

Comment: `your_counter = Counter(crime_list) ;  print(your_counter)`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille its running right now, but the datasest is very large so it might take a while. I'll comment back once it's complete and let you know if it worked!